# Create new column in Data Frame and fill by computing the differences of consecutive rows for certain columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, multiple-columns, diff

I have a dataframe with column A B and C. where A= Timeseries, B = ID and C = Utilization.

My Output is generating new columns such as (Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4) in dataframe depending on the length of the timeseries data for particular id.  I am able to acchieve the first column using  .diff method but not able to execute the shifting of values from col1 to col2 and so on. Any help would be appreciated on how to acchieve this for each unique id.

```
A  B  C   col1   col2 col3 col4
0  1   a   a-c) (c-e)   e-g  g
1  1   c   (c-e) (e-g)    g
2  1   e   (e-g)  g
3  1   g    g
```

New data Sample per groups

```
ID   Period   OS    c1       C2      C3      C4     C5
1    Jan-21   100   100-80   80-70   70-60   60-40  40
1    Feb-21   80    80-70    70-60   60-40    40    nan
1    Mar-21   70    70-60    60-40    40      nan   nan
1    Apr-21   60    60-40     40       nan    nan   nan
1    May-21   40    40        nan      nan    nan   nan

2    Mar-21   200   200-100   100-50   50     
2    Apr-21   100   100-50     50      nan
2    May-21   50    50         nan     nan
```

Comment: "A B C col1 col2 col3 col4 0 1 a a-c) (c-e) e-g g 1 1 c (c-e) (e-g) g 2 1 e (e-g) g 3 1 g g"
is this ur current output?

Answer (score -1):

You can use helper series by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then create new columns by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) per groups:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['OS'].diff(-1).fillna(df['OS'])

for x in np.arange(df['ID'].value_counts().max()):
    df[f'C{x+1}'] = s.groupby(df['ID']).shift(-x)
    
print (df)
   ID  Period   OS     C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
0   1  Jan-21  100   20.0  10.0  10.0  20.0  40.0
1   1  Feb-21   80   10.0  10.0  20.0  40.0   NaN
2   1  Mar-21   70   10.0  20.0  40.0   NaN   NaN
3   1  Apr-21   60   20.0  40.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   1  May-21   40   40.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5   2  Mar-21  200  100.0  50.0  50.0   NaN   NaN
6   2  Apr-21  100   50.0  50.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
7   2  May-21   50   50.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks..How can we implement this for each unique Id?

Comment: yes, i think i can

Comment: @Jezerel, i have update the new sample...but I am not sure why its in distorted form